# Linphone Android Build Compile Error: ChatMessagesFragment is not abstract

Tags: android, android-studio, linphone, linphone-sdk

When I try to compile the latest master or 4.3.1 codebase for Linphone android, I face this error. I am using Android Studio 4.1.2. I tried downloading the zip file as well as clone the repo. Both ends up with this error. If I implement the blank methods for **onChatMessageSending(ChatRoom,EventLog)** and **onNewEvent(ChatRoom chatRoom, EventLog eventLog)**in ChatMessagesFragment then it fixes the compile error. However I want to know is this something that is expected or am I missing something that is causing this error?

```
/GitHub/linphone-android4_3_1/app/src/main/java/org/linphone/chat/ChatMessagesFragment.java:95: error: ChatMessagesFragment is not abstract and does not override abstract method onNewEvent(ChatRoom,EventLog) in ChatRoomListener
public class ChatMessagesFragment extends Fragment
```

```
/GitHub/linphone-android4_3_1/app/src/main/java/org/linphone/chat/ChatMessagesFragment.java:95: error: ChatMessagesFragment is not abstract and does not override abstract method onChatMessageSending(ChatRoom,EventLog) in ChatRoomListener
public class ChatMessagesFragment extends Fragment
```

Answer (score 1):

The master branch of Linphone-Android has been [troublesome to build recently](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-android/commits/master), I was able to [build the release/4.4 branch](https://git.callpipe.com/linphone/linphone-android/-/jobs/14302) (which is a few commits ahead of the master branch currently), try rebasing your changes onto this branch?